# Python combine tuples together

Tags: python, tuples

I have multiple tuples:

```
# First
first = (('Var1', (10, 25)),
         ('Var2', (25, 28)),
         ('Var3', (28, 31)),
         ('Var4', (31, 34)),
         ('Var5', (34, 44)))

# Second
second = (('Var6', (44, 50)))

# Third
third = (('Var7', (50, 60)),
         ('Var8', (60, 65)),
         ('Var9', (65, 70)))
```

How can I combine them correctly.

```
first + second + third

(('Var1', (10, 25)),
 ('Var2', (25, 28)),
 ('Var3', (28, 31)),
 ('Var4', (31, 34)),
 ('Var5', (34, 44)),
 'Var6',
 (44, 50),
 ('Var7', (50, 60)),
 ('Var8', (60, 65)),
 ('Var9', (65, 70)))
```

However, how can it combine as below:

```
( ('Var1', (10, 25)),
  ('Var2', (25, 28)),
  ('Var3', (28, 31)),
  ('Var4', (31, 34)),
  ('Var5', (34, 44)),
  ('Var6', (44, 50)),
  ('Var7', (50, 60)),
  ('Var8', (60, 65)),
  ('Var9', (65, 70)) )
```

The second one is not correctly combined...

Comment: Your second tuple isn't nested the way the others are. To make it like the others, you should define it as `second = (('Var6', (44, 50)),)`

Comment: StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service. You should add into your question your honest and best code attempt to solve this problem as a [mre] and show its output. Explain how that could perhaps be improved.

Comment: To expand on @khelwood's comment: one-element tuples have a funny syntax.  `(item)` is not a one-element tuple -- it's just a value with parens.  You have to say `(item,)` to make it a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-element tuple literals require a comma to be recognised as tuples. So `('content')` isn't a tuple, but `('content',)` is.

Your second tuple has this problem. It isn't nested the way the others are. That's why you don't get the output you want.

Either change the definition of `second` to

```
second = (('Var6', (44, 50)),)
#       Note the comma here ^
```

**OR** change your combination expression to

```
first + (second,) + third
```

That will give

```
(('Var1', (10, 25)),
 ('Var2', (25, 28)),
 ('Var3', (28, 31)),
 ('Var4', (31, 34)),
 ('Var5', (34, 44)),
 ('Var6', (44, 50)),
 ('Var7', (50, 60)),
 ('Var8', (60, 65)),
 ('Var9', (65, 70)))
```